# WYSIWYG javascript editor usable for forum?

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg

I'm currently having a hard time finding a WYSIWYG editor that can be integrated as an editor for a forum. I've already looked at the famous ones like tinyMCE and CKeditor, but they don't work how I expect them to work.

The problem is, I want to have nested visible quotation. Therefore, it's, in my opinion, required that I use nested blockquotes, which they do not seem to support.

Indents/outdents are implemented by not-nested, styled p-tags and nesting blockquotes does not seem to be possible, even though it's, as far as I know, valid HTML.

Ideally, it would be an editor, which isn't backed by a big JavaScript framework. I don't want to include ExtJS, for example, for such, and it should work for nested quotation as I expect. For example, from an native e-mail client which means, nested visualized quotations, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key in a quotation breaks the quotation to let you answer, etc.

The rest should be like the normal pro-editors, uncluttered HTML output, compatible with all major browsers, etc.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I find CKEditor very configurable.  Though it may not always work as I like - you would agree - I can customize it easily.  And even though the native blockquote doesn't work as you like, the cut-and-paste from email should be even easier to customize.  Have you tried customizing?

Comment: i would love to customize CKeditor, because it's very fast, produces uncluttered html and seems to be well coded. however, i thought i ask over at stackoverflow if someone has an idea, before diving deeper into the code, because i think it might not be that easy to modiy the blockquote behaviour (and i've limited time as always :( ) -- also i think there must be any reason, why those editors don't support nested blockquotes? i've found a commit-message at CKeditor repository, where it seems they have removed it between 2.4 and 2.6 ...

Comment: Interesting.  Makes you wonder.  What version of CKEditor are you using?

Comment: i'm using the current release -- 3.0.1. however, i as i really like CKeditor i'll have a look at the code and try if i am able to implement what i need -- thanks anyway!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question at all, but if you're using a HTML editor for your forum, you know you need to do really heavyweight sanitization of the HTML to prevent XSS, right? More info here: http://directwebremoting.org/blog/joe/2007/10/29/web_application_security.html

Comment: I think you'll find CKEditor easily customizable.  I typically include individual source files after the minimized ckeditor.js while I debug; these individual files override the equivalent code in ckeditor.js.

Comment: @Annie: yes, i know ... but i think i can handle this and if the editor produces uncluttered code itself, it should be easier to filter unwanted stuff, i think. thanks for the link, anyway -- it's always appreciated :)

Comment: @Upper Stage: that's a good idea. thanks for sharing! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fckeditor/

and (from Yahoo):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/

Dunno if either one does exactly what you are looking for, but they're worth checking out.

Comment: Oh, heh, didn't realize that.  Well, the YUI one is still worth looking in to :-)

Comment: CKEditor is best. Customizable,skinnable.